# Add a method to a class-based lookup table via decorators in ECMAScript 6

Tags: ecmascript-6, decorator

In ES6, I want to do something like

```
class Foo extends Bar {  
  @Map('toCall')
  someFunction() {
    ...
  }
}
```

and later

```
foo = new Foo();
Foo.MAGIC_LOOKUP_TABLE['toCall'](foo);
```

in order to effectively call `foo.someFunction();`.

The intended use case is to let the programmer in charge of Foo dictate which function should be called only with a decorator change.

However, when writing:

```
export function Map(str) {
  return function(target, name, descriptor) {
    // ???
  };
}
```

I can not for the life of me figure out how to get anything like `Foo` where you see ??? above.   `target` seems to be a `prototype` value shared by all subclasses of `Bar` that attempt to use `@Map`.

How can I best achieve this?  I do not want the author of Foo's javascript file to have to know about `MAGIC_LOOKUP_TABLE`, but instead to merely annotate the method to be called.

Comment: Shouldn't `prototype.constructor` work? How do you expect this to work with subclasses?

Comment: Actually, which proposal is this using? Doesn't look like https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators

Comment: Felix, because it's multi-line?  Considered @logged in that link.  Anyway, I've got it working with "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators".  `target.constructor` was the missing sauce, submit as answer and I'll accept.